# Test-boot hard drive in QEMU, without writing to it

Tags: qemu, snapshot

I remember reading a cool command to use QEMU, to test-boot a hard drive, but without writing anything back to it.  (Even if the system is EFI-booted, I think it should be able to work for Linux if you can use the `-kernel`, `-initrd`, and `-append` options).

It was mentioned in the context of testing systemd, if that jogs anyone's memory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the QEMU manpage, and it looks like you're thinking of the `-snapshot` option.

**Do not press `Ctrl-a s`.   It will copy the snapshot back to the physical disk**

Knowing that, I was able to find my source:

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/VirtualizedTesting/

(Additional note.  On a modern Wayland system, you may need to use `xhost +si:localuser:root` to get `sudo qemu` to work).